# How to make a polynomial with all roots real?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

How can I make a polynomial of degree $n$ with all $n$ roots real? Is there a way to do this for any degree polynomial? For quadratics it is required that the discriminant is larger than 0, but how for any degree?

Comment: What are the parameters that you can control in this scenario?

Comment: parameters? the only parameters you can control for a polynomial are the coefficients.

Comment: If the polynomial is $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$, then one way is to make all coefficients zero.

Comment: In the question, you say nothing about the coefficients rather you are talking about the discriminant. There are several ways in which you can make a polynomial have real roots. It all depends on the way you are trying to represent the polynomial and the parameters or rather the things which you can change in order to get the desired result. If you want to track the change with respect to the coefficients then I'll have some kind of a answer and if you want to track the behaviours of discriminant, that will be another answer.

Comment: Does it need to be n distinct roots ?

Comment: the discriminant describes the coefficients, thats all it does, so i have no idea what you're on about. how can i customise any polynomial to have all real roots? all i can change are the coefficients. its a simple question.

Comment: Why not just take $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$ to be your polynomial?

Comment: deepak, put that as the answer. it solves the problem. thanks!

Comment: I've done so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just take $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$ to be your polynomial.